# Errors in c++ faq lite?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm reading questions and answers around here for a few days.
I have seen the [c++ faq lite at Parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) has been mentioned many times. Personally I have always considered it to be a good reference, not my favourite one but certainly useful.
Here I have seen somebody advising it, but many others commenting against it instead.
Somebody mentioned it's full of mistakes.
Could you please point out which are the major errors in there, if any?

Comment: I also think the c++ faq lite is a good reference. It's also being continuously updated, so one would hope that if someone finds an error in it they contact the maintainer instead of moaning about it on message boards.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing it with the [C++ FQA](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/)?

Comment: @FredOverflow i'm sure, i didn't post link cause i don't want to accuse anybody. I'd really like to now if there's anything wrong

Comment: The FQA is funny in its witty (most of the times) humor... but I don't think we would really benefit from trying to track its mistakes.

Comment: Feel free to post a link. You're not "accusing" anyone of anything, simply asking what mistakes they're talking about.

Comment: This appears to be the FAQ in question: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any error in the FAQ.  In fact, I've learn very much from the FAQ and in many cases I was wrong.

Sometimes the compilers have errors, and if you try to use some of the tricks in old compilers they will not work.